# Loop backwards won't loop and find variable

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

I have tried several thing with different types of looping lastrow -1 , I have done it forwards no problem..Backwards fails to do loop or find.Empty row on found variable which creates empty row above variable

```
Sub ColAInsertrow() '===================================yay
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim LastRow As Long, FirstRow As Long
    Dim Row As Long
    
    With ActiveSheet
        'Define First and Last Rows
        FirstRow = 1
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        
        'Loop Through Rows (Bottom to Top)
        For Row = LastRow To FirstRow Step -1
            If .Range("A" & Row).Value = ("Transactions for*") Then
                .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
             ElseIf .Range("A" & Row).Value = ("Start") Then
                                
            End If
        Next Row
    End With
    
    ' Call MoveHTotals
    '  Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

[image: [![sheet i am trying to manipulate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAsKA.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAsKA.png)]

Comment: Your code looks ok, but it doesn't match the data in the table. `transaction` is not the same as `Transaction`

Comment: That is why I had both capitalized and non cap. in the find area, but it doesn't make a difference whether the are Cap. or non cap.  I may not be  understand you comment then, thanks

Comment: Thank you all for suggestions, I must be dense, I don't recognize any changes to code. I understand the formatting, but don't see changes or guidance.

Comment: `If .Range("A" & Row).Value Like "Transactions for*" Then` You can't use wildcards with `=`

Answer (score 0):

UsedRange can be deceiving. For me it sometimes stops at the first blank row. In your example, right after the "start" row.

```
        If .Range("A" & Row).Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(.Range("A" & Row).Value, "Transactions for") > 0 Then
                .Range("A" & Row).EntireRow.Insert
            ElseIf .Range("A" & Row).Value = ("Start") Then
                            
            End If
        End If
```

Comment: mmmm deleted empty row after "start", no change...   perplexed

Comment: It works as it should now Nick, Appreciate all who contributed, this is part of an execercize that is about 60,000 rows.